# How to clear React-hook-form dependent field errors

Tags: react-hook-form

I want to create a form with min, max and desired fields.

**The logic can be this:**

- Min, Desired, Max cannot be Zero or negative
- Desired should be greater than or equal to Min. And less than or
  equal to Max
- Max should be greater than or equal to Desired/Min

I provider default value as 1 for all fields

```
const { register, getValues, handleSubmit, formState: { errors }} = useForm({
  mode: "onChange",
  defaultValues: {
    min: 1,
    desired: 1,
    max: 1
  }
});
```

and validated inside the field

```
<MyField 
  {...register("desired", {
    validate: (value) => {
      const min = getValues("min");
      const max = getValues("max");
                
       if (value < min)
         return "Desired must be greater than or equal to min";
                
       if (value > max) return "Desired must be less than max";
     }
   })
  } 
/>
```

When the user increase the desired number error will happen(due to max is low than desired). After user increase the max number the error still there...

[CSB](https://codesandbox.io/s/rhf-interactive-field-ien3c?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `deps` to trigger validation on others fields
https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register

[image]

You can user `trigger` from `useForm` as well

We recommend to use `watch` instead of `getValues` to get a field value. `watch` have better performances.

The working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rhf-interactive-field-forked-yb7jo?file=/src/App.js

You might adjust some settings to match your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Joris. It seems like the CSB link also not solves my issue

Comment: Can you tell me what's wrong ?

Comment: [![image.png](https://i.postimg.cc/3NwpnjSx/image.png)](https://postimg.cc/phgpdjMw) this should be valid

Comment: Thanks, I get it. I've updated the codesandbox. Have a look and give me a feedback

Comment: How to use `deps` for my use case...